# How to do an OR query in Google App Engine

Tags: mysql, database, google-app-engine

I have a model called `RelatedUsers` with has three properties:

```
firstUserId 
secondUserId 
relationshipStatus
```

I'm coming from MySQL where I would do this:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM relatedUsers WHERE (firstUserId='$originatorId' 
AND secondUserId='$recipientId') OR (firstUserId='$recipientId' 
AND secondUserId='$originatorId')");
```

How can I do something like this with Google App Engine? I can't find any similar cases online..

Comment: You don't. The datastore doesn't support it.

Comment: Any OR's are unsupported in general?

Comment: You're basically asking for two different queries anyway. It looks like your query is designed to return one record for each, though, in which case it would make much more sense to use the combined user IDs of both users as the key name for your 'RelatedUsers' entity. Then, you can retrieve them with a batch get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by running several queries for the keys and then fetching the keys.

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

class User(ndb.Model):
    email = db.StringProperty()


options = ndb.QueryOptions(keys_only=True)
condition_1 = ndb.Query(User, options=options).filter(User.email == "mom@home.com")
condition_1 = ndb.Query(User, options=options).filter(User.email == "dad@home.com")

key_list = list(set(list(condition_1) + list(condition_2)))

mom_and_dad = ndb.get_multi(key_list)
```

If you have to order them you will have to do that in memory.

/done from memory :)